# Android - Supported Image Types

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-photos

i have searched on the Image types supported by Android everywhere.

Actually, my confusion is **`which are image types supported by Android`** (i.e. JPEG, gif, or other) , because just now i have done camera capturing code with JPEG, but when i go and open the Albums from my HTC Hero, then i cant view photos and images which i have captured.
so **`should i not captured photos with extension as .jpeg??`**

The error shown in Alert box are: **`"The application Albums(process.com.htc.album) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again".`**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Supported media formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

> This document describes the media codec, container, and network protocol support provided by the Android platform.
>
> <sub>As an application developer, you are free to make use of any media codec that is available on any Android-powered device, including those provided by the Android platform and those that are device-specific. **However, it is a best practice to use media encoding profiles that are device-agnostic**...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Supported media formats are : PNG, BMP, WEBP(for Android 4 and above)

Comment: It is already listed in above link mentioned by @Key, and so JPEG and GIF are also supporting now :)